# re-binding jquery selectors in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have a very simple angular application that has one service which uses a http request to pull down a web page. I then want to display that page within my application using `ng-bind-html`.

template:

```
<div class="container" ng-bind-html="data"></div>
```

controller:

```
this.service.getHoliday().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
});
```

this works from a visual perspective, however it would appear the javascript/jquery files are loaded but not used. I feel like this is because the elements are not available when it is run.

I feel like the best option to resolve this is to somehow rebind all the elements, is it possible to rebind the entire page without caring about each individual selector.

I've tried using a `$apply()` method, wrapping the above like so:

```
this.service.getHoliday().then(function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    });
});
```

but this stops the page from loading the html completely, i understand that this is vague but hopefully someone has come up against a similar issue that can help.

Comment: I can tell you why `$apply` has no affect and errors at least. That is designed to tell angular to run a digest cycle should the scope change outside of the Angular framework, so a jQuery event handler, callback etc. Should it be called inside the Angular framework, as you are, a digest cycle will already be in progress, so it throws an exception and the action is halted, so the HTML doesn't get rendered.

Comment: Are you inject `ngSanitize` in your module?

Comment: thanks @ste2425 i think what i was hoping it would do is re-trigger the digest so it would re-run the js within the html i'm rendering but alas this must be magic i've made up in my head.

Comment: @shaishabroy i wasn't, but it seems to make no difference if i do